# Can't call findViewById() while working with Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

While studying Kotlin, I got trouble with fragment sessions.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("life_cycle", "F onViewCreated")

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val pass: Button = findViewById(R.id.pass)

    pass.setOnClickListener {
        dataPassListener.onDataPass("Good bye")
    }
}
```

I want to write `val pass: Button = findViewById(R.id.pass)`, but I can't use `findViewById()`.

I think the problem is that `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` is not imported.

Comment: What class is this function in? The answer has more to do with what class this class extends rather than what classes are imported.

Comment: Please use view.findViewById()

Answer (score 5):

Guessing from what you've written, this snippet is from one of your classes that extends some variant of the `Fragment` class.

If this is the case, what you want to do is:

```
val pass: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.pass)
```

The difference here is that `findViewById()` is invoked against the `view` instance passed in the lifecycle callback.

(This assumes that the `R.id.pass` resource is defined in the view inflated by this Fragment).

Answer (score 1):

you have to use view.findViewById

```
val pass: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.pass)
```